# Rename file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I need to find files of the form '*abc.111*' in a directory and rename  them as '*abc.222*' in my shell script. The pattern substitution fails somehow. What am I missing here?

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -name \*abc\* | while read FILES
do
        newfile =  ${FILES/111/222} #Replace 111 by 222
        mv $FILES $newfile
done
```

Error : /temp.sh: bad substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/bin/sh` does not support `${var//}` substitution.  Try another shell, such as `/bin/bash`.

Once you fix that, you will find that spaces do not work.

```
newfile =  ${FILES/111/222}
```

You must write this line without spaces on either side of `=`.